# Asymptotic equivalence and sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Suppose that for every $k \geq 1$:

$$ f_k (x) \sim c_k g(x), \quad x \to \infty,$$

where $f_k(x)$ and $g(x)$ are some positive functions and the $c_k$ nonnegative constants. My question is whether for every $m \geq 1$:
$$  \sum_{k=1}^m f_k (x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^m c_k g(x), \quad x \to \infty. \label{1}\tag{1} $$
I would think so, because when considering the limit of the quotient of both sides, one could just divide by $g(x)$. The harder question is whether then even
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k g(x), \quad x \to \infty. \label{2}\tag{2}$$
Here, I am not sure anymore that this is true. Does this follow from \eqref{1}?

Note that $f(x) \sim g(x)$ if $f(x)/ g(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Is it $g(x)$ or $g_k (x)$?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is false in general. Equivalence is compatible with products, quotients or exponentiation to a fixed power, but not with addition in general.

*Counterexample*:

$1+x\sim_0 1$, $-1\sim -1$, but $1+x -1\not \sim_0 1-1=0$.

Comment: What does $\sim_0$ mean?

Comment: ‘equivalent  near $0$ to’

Comment: @VarunVejalla Or asymptotic when $x\to 0$.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's like $1+ 1/x$ when $x \to \infty$? I think, that your example does not satisfy the conditions that I proposed ($c_k$ is ought to be nonnegative). Do you also have a counterexample when $g(x)$ is not a constant and $f_k(x)$ and $g(x)$ have no constant part?

Comment: @Sebastiano (and Bernard) Thanks for the explanation! I probably should have been able to guess that.

Comment: @VarunVejalla We're here to help you...:-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused regarding this counterexample (specifically, why are you multiplying by $x$ to get $1 + x-1\color{red}{x}$?). Could you please state explicitly what $g(x), f_1(x), f_2(x), c_1, c_2$ are?

Comment: I will just put here my proof for the part with the finite sum: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sum_k^m f_k (x) } { \sum_k^m c_k g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_k^m f_k (x) / g(x) } { \sum_k^m c_k} = \frac{ \sum_k^m c_k} { \sum_k^m c_k} = 1$$

Comment: @FelixP.: I don't have one in mind at the moment (and it's getting late here), but I'll try to find one tomorrow. If you read french, there's this good page: [Opérations sur les équivalents](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opérations_sur_les_équivalents)  which doesn't exist in english.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know a bit French and will have a look.

Comment: The spurious $x$ was a simple typo. I've fixed  that. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: No: the ratio doesn't tend to $1$.

Comment: OP wants non-negative functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The important point, when testing convergence  via equivalence, is that functions have (ultimately) a constant sign.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplicity I assume $x\in (0,\infty)$. The equality \eqref{2} can fail, for instance, when $f_k(x)=1$, $g_k(x)=1+2^k/x$, and $c_k=1/2^k$  for each $k$ and $x$. In this case the left-hand side of \eqref{2} equals $1$, whereas the right-hand side is unbounded.